# Ajax: post array of integers to Django

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

I'm using [DataTables](http://www.datatables.net). I want to let the user select multiple rows and delete them. So far I have it working so it deletes the first row in the selection using the code below.

Ajax Code:

```
    /* Add a click handler for the delete row */
    $('#delete').click( function() {
        /* fnGetSelected returns an array of integers - each int is a db unique id */
        var anSelected = fnGetSelected( oTable );
        delete_url = '/delete/' + anSelected[0];               
        $.ajax({                  
              url: delete_url,
              type: 'GET',
          });
        oTable.fnDeleteRow( anSelected[0] ); 
        fnReloadAjax();
    } );
```

Django Code:

```
@login_required
def delete(request, row_id):                          
     item = get_object_or_404(Items, pk=row_id, user=request.user)
     item.delete()
```

How could I update this to pass all the row ids to the Django back end? I guess I need to POST the anSelected array, but am not sure how to do this. What Django code would I need to process this integer array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need to use `simplejson.loads`, for example if you'd pass the anSelected array as `arr` you'd use something like this

```
from django.utils import simplejson

array = simplejson.loads(request.POST['arr'])
try:
    ModelName.objects.filter(pk__in=array).delete()
except:
    return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps({'ok': False}))
return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps({'ok': True}))
```

and in your javascript this something along these lines:

```
$.post(
    '/delete/',
    {arr: anSelected},
    function(data){
        if(data.ok){
            //Everything went smoothly
        }else{
            //Something failed, you can send extra info from django like the name of the exception thrown if you'd want and display it
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm getting "invalid property id" error on the {arr: anSelected} line.

Comment: Revised my code, just a syntax error because of the extra curly braces :)

Answer (score 6):

You could try sometings like this:

```
$(function(){
    $.post("{% url delete %}", {"ids[]": anSelected}, function(res){
    if(res.ok){
        // remove rows from your table, maybe :)
        // oTable.fnDeleteRow(anSelected);
      }else{
        alert(res.errors); 
      } 
    });
})
```

On the server:

```
@ajax_request
def test(request):
    ids = request.POST.getlist("ids[]")
    try:
        Items.objects.filter(id__in=ids).delete()
    except:
        return {"ok": False, "errors": "your error"}
    return {"ok": True}
```

the @ajax_request decorators is from https://bitbucket.org/offline/django-annoying/wiki/Home and let you return json response.

Comment: POST.getlist was the key here. Helpful for getting data in DJANGO  from arrays resulting from forms